# Can a nested directory be uploaded to a Snowflake stage?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, staging

Is Snowflake smart enough to be able to stage a nested directory?

For example, currently I have a folder with a few files:

```
- Folder1:
    - file1.csv
    - file2.csv
    - ...
    - file9.csv
```

And I am able to stage all 9 .csvs with a simple wild card. However, let's say I have a nested folder with the files as such:

```
- Folder
    - Folder1:
        * file1.csv
        * file2.csv
        * file3.csv
    - Folder2:
        * file4.csv...
```

and so on and so forth. Is there a way, or is Snowflake smart enough, for me to point just to `Folder` so it knows every subfolder contains the actual .csvs?

*Edit: I am using the `put` command in the command line interface to stage the files.

Comment: uploaded/stage implies you are using a PUT command. Which is different from my point, but a COPY command against S3 can handled "nested paths" just fine.

Comment: but, `Wildcard characters (*, ?) are supported to enable uploading multiple files in a directory.` those words sound rather like a NO answer. You could move a file to a sub-directory and try..

Comment: Can you specify how you are you going to stage these files?

Comment: probably should have specified - im using the command line interface and the `put` command to stage these files. i will edit the question to reflect that

Comment: I was able to make it upload files in subfolders using `**`, like this: `PUT file://./folder/**/** @stage_name`. It loads all files into one place. I wish I was able to just tell it to use a folder and it would upload all tree structure instead of flat files.